# array match values filter PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have tried to search within an array but did not get any result at all.

Suppose I have a array which contains some values.

So when I want to search them, it always return null!

Do not know the reason why!

Suppose this is my array--

```
$data = Array
    (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 122
        [name] => Fast and furious 5
        [category] => Game
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 232
        [name] => Battlefield and more 
        [category] => Game
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 324
        [name] => Titanic the legend
        [category] => movie
    )

    [3] => Array
    ....
```

So I have tried like this--

```
   $search = 'and'; // what I want to search
   $nameSearch = array_search($search, $data);
   print_r($nameSearch);
```

Output -- empty

```
   $search='and'; // what i want to search
   $nameSearch=  array_filter($search, $data);
   print_r($nameSearch);
```

Output -- empty

The goal is to find the values which matches anything from the array.

Means, if I request "and" in return I should get

```
Fast and furious 5
Battlefield and more
```

Because of of the value contains "and".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`array_filter` and `array_search` look for exact matches. Combine `array_filter` with `stripos` instead if you want partial matches:

```
$search = 'and';

print_r(array_filter($data,function($a) use ($search) {
    return stripos($a['name'],$search) !== false;
}));
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your great answer, but i am keep getting an error like **Warning: stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given** for the line ***return stripos($a,$search) !== false;**

Comment: @ChristoferHansen the error seems to indicate that `$data` is an array of arrays as opposed to an array of strings as it is in your example

Comment: @yes it is an array of a array

Comment: @ChristoferHansen in that case you'll need to specify the key containing the string i.e. `return stripos($a['title'],$search) !== false;`

Comment: i am getting empty values, i have update my question values can u kindly have a look, please

Comment: @ChristoferHansen did you try `$a['name']` as the key? see update

Comment: it return me **Warning: Illegal string offset 'name'**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91929/discussion-between-fuzzytree-and-christofer-hansen).

Answer (score 3):

This will work for you

```
 <?php
$array = array('Fast and furious ', 'Titanic the legend', 'Battlefield and more ', 'India', 'Brazil', 'Croatia', 'Denmark');
$search = preg_grep('/and.*/', $array);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($search );
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: nice, `preg_grep` is cleaner than combining `array_filter` with `stripos`

Comment: @FuzzyTree But `preg_grep` will have it's Limits for complex Arrays - `array_filter` is more versatile.

Comment: @marius thanks for your answer, but it will not work for me cause i always need the post values